# Cache of share in windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block, cifs

I have a folder, which is shared by Windows Server 2012 R2. When I setup this share, I saw in the configure share setting panel, it has a check box for `Allow caching of share` with the comment `Caching makes the contents of the share avaiable to offline users`. I chose this option, but when connection between the client and server is lost, I cannot see contents of the share. Do I misunderstand this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably missing the fact that Offline Files must be enabled on the client side in order for files and programs accessed from the Share to be cached offline. Additionally, only files and programs that have been opened from the Share are made available offline. Simply accessing the Share doesn't cache it's contents in the Offline Files cache.

Comment: @Waveter here's a Microsoft page that shows how to set up the client to actually cache the files you've made available from the server. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/working-with-network-files-offline#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Glad to help...